# LXML don't want to parse text after comment

Tags: python, xml, lxml, cdata

I want to wrap tag.text into CDATA:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
  <tag>
    some data
    <!-- some data2 -->
    <!-- some data2 -->
    some data
  </tag>
</root>
```

But when i parse tag.text with comments inside it parse only text before comments:

```
from lxml import etree

parser = etree.XMLParser()
#parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_comments=True)
tree = etree.parse("./data.xml", parser)
root = tree.getroot()

for tag in root.findall("tag"):
    tag.text = etree.CDATA(tag.text)

tree.write("./result.xml",
           encoding = "utf-8",
           xml_declaration = True)
```

And i get this (tag.text = some data):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<root>
  <tag><![CDATA[
    some data
    ]]><!-- some data2 -->
    <!-- some data2 -->
    some data
  </tag>
</root>
```

How to fix it?

Comment: The second occurrence of "some data" is in the `tail` of the second comment. It is not part of the `text` of the `<tag>` element.

Comment: tag.tail returns nothing

Comment: Yes, the `tail` of `<tag>` is empty. But the `tail` of the second comment is "some data" (plus whitespace).

Comment: okey, it is in tag[1].tail, but it's uncomfortable to me to separate text into tag.text, comments and tag.tail and then merge them back, any way to parse them together?

Answer (score 1):

Consider to use saxonche and XSLT 3.0:

```
from saxonche import *

with PySaxonProcessor(license=False) as saxon_proc:
    xslt30_processor = saxon_proc.new_xslt30_processor()

    xslt30_processor.transform_to_file(source_file='sample1.xml', stylesheet_file='serialize-wrap-in-cdata1.xsl', output_file='result-sample1.xml')
```

XSLT 3 is e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="cdata-tag-names" as="xs:string*" static="yes" select="'tag'"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" _cdata-section-elements="{$cdata-tag-names}"/>

  <xsl:template _match="{$cdata-tag-names => string-join(' | ')}">
    <xsl:copy>{serialize(node())}</xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

sample1.xml is your input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
  <tag>
    some data
    <!-- some data2 -->
    <!-- some data2 -->
    some data
  </tag>
</root>
```

Public Gist with the files: https://gist.github.com/martin-honnen/61b91233fd73369d55f392ad4a0cee0b.

Example fiddle using SaxonC HE is at this [link](https://saxonc-xmlworkbench.azurewebsites.net/?code=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20expand-text%3D%22yes%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aparam%20name%3D%22cdata-tag-names%22%20as%3D%22xs%3Astring*%22%20static%3D%22yes%22%20select%3D%22%27foo%27%2C%20%27foobar%27%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Amode%20on-no-match%3D%22shallow-copy%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aoutput%20method%3D%22xml%22%20_cdata-section-elements%3D%22%7B%24cdata-tag-names%7D%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20_match%3D%22%7B%24cdata-tag-names%20%3D%3E%20string-join%28%27%20%7C%20%27%29%7D%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Acopy%3E%7Bserialize%28node%28%29%29%7D%3C%2Fxsl%3Acopy%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E&input=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%20%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Croot%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3Cfoo%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20some%20data%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%21--%20some%20data2%20--%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%21--%20some%20data2%20--%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20some%20data%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Ffoo%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3Ctag%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20some%20data%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%21--%20some%20data2%20--%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%21--%20some%20data2%20--%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20some%20data%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Ftag%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3Cfoobar%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20some%20data%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%21--%20some%20data2%20--%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%21--%20some%20data2%20--%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20some%20data%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Ffoobar%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Froot%3E&code-type=XSLT&input-type=XML).

Comment: Is this open source or licensed package?

Comment: saxonche is the open source edition of SaxonC: https://pypi.org/project/saxonche/. There are commercial packages saxoncpe and saxoncee as well but they provide features like schema-aware XSLT and XQuery, streamed XSLT that I have not used in my answer at all. The code in the answer is XSLT 3 as supported by SaxonC HE, Saxon Java HE, Saxon.NET HE  (or SaxonJS for client-side JS and Node (SaxonJS is not open source but is not requiring any license purchase))

Comment: Great thanks. Should CDATA not escaped? Could this be done by XSLT3 also?

Comment: Creating a CDATA is a serialization feature which is done in the posted XSLT 3 by `<xsl:output method="xml" _cdata-section-elements="{$cdata-tag-names}"/>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to concatenate all of the text within the `<tag>` elements, you can use the `str.join` method on the elements `itertext` method.  This will join all of the text including whitespaces before passing to the `CDATA` method.

```
for tag in root.findall("tag"):
    tag.text = etree.CDATA(''.join(tag.itertext()))
```

The comments are considered child elements of the  `<tag>` element in your example.  The tail text is iterated over when using the `itertext` method.

Comment: I tried this. Firstly, it didn't parse comments, i also need to save comments in CDATA. Secondly, it modify only tag.text, so we will get this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<root>
  <tag><![CDATA[
    some data1
    
    
    some data4
  ]]><!-- some data2 -->
    <!-- some data3 -->
    some data4
  </tag>
</root>
```

Comment: But I understood that I should iterate over tag.text and elements of tag and concatenate them. Ty

Answer (score 0):

I found tricky way to parse and modify text, comments and tails together:

```
tmp = etree.tostring(tag).decode()
// here you need to remove <tag> from tmp string
tag.clear()
tag.text = etree.CDATA(tmp)
```

If someone knows more correct/beautiful way to do this (for example, something like tag.all), please write.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over `tag` element to get it's text + text representation of comment elements (without tail text) + any tail text (which includes indentation). Then remove that child and populate tag element with CDATA wrapped text.

```
from lxml import etree

parser = etree.XMLParser()
tree = etree.parse("tmp.xml", parser)
root = tree.getroot()

for s in root.findall("tag"):
    t = s.text
    for ele in s.iterchildren():
        t += etree.tostring(ele, with_tail=False).decode("utf8")
        t += ele.tail
        # remove item
        ele.getparent().remove(ele)
    s.text = etree.CDATA(t)
    #print(etree.tostring(s).decode("utf8"))

print(etree.tostring(tree, with_tail=True).decode("utf8"))
```

Result

```
<root>
  <tag><![CDATA[
    some data
    <!-- some data2 -->
    <!-- some data2 -->
    some data
  ]]></tag>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

`xml.etree.ElementTree` has `ET.iterparse()` who detects events, including comments:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from io import StringIO

xml_file = f"""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
  <tag>
    some data 1
    <!-- some data2 -->
    <!-- some data3 -->
    some data 4
  </tag>
</root>
"""

f = StringIO(xml_file)

for event, elem in ET.iterparse(f, events=('start','comment')):
    if elem.tag == 'tag' and event == 'start':
        print('Text start', elem.text)
    if '<function Comment' in repr(elem.tag):
        print("Comment", elem.text)
```

Output:

```
Text start 
    some data 1
    
    
    some data 4
  
Comment  some data2 
Comment  some data3
```

And here the `lxml` adoption:

```
from lxml import etree
from io import BytesIO

xml_file = f"""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
  <tag>
    some data 1
    <!-- some data2 -->
    <!-- some data3 -->
    some data 4
  </tag>
</root>
"""

f = BytesIO(xml_file.encode('utf-8'))

def cdata (text):
    tex = ' '.join(text)
    root = etree.Element('root')
    tag = etree.SubElement(root, 'tag')
    tag.text = etree.CDATA(tex)
    etree.dump(root)
    


tex=[]
for event, elem in etree.iterparse(f, events=('start','comment')):
    if elem.tag == 'tag' and event == 'start':
        tex.append(elem.text.strip())
        
    if '<cyfunction Comment' in repr(elem.tag):
        com = f"<!--{elem.text}-->"
        tex.append(com)
        tex.append(elem.tail.strip())

cdata(tex)
```

Output:

```
<root>
  <tag><![CDATA[some data 1 <!-- some data2 -->. <!-- some data3 -->  some data 4]]></tag>
</root>
```